# Why is keras custom layer producing nonsense output shape in summary

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I've defined a custom layer in keras:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
import keras
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
    def call(self, emb):
        emb = K.repeat_elements(emb, 6, 2)
        return emb

inputs = Input(shape=(2,1))
outputs = MyLayer()(inputs)
print(outputs.shape)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()


(?, 2, 6)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_16 (InputLayer)        (None, 2, 1)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
my_layer_8 (MyLayer)         (None, 2, 1)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model.output.shape is (None, 2, 6), just as expected, but in the summary it says the output shape of my layer is (None, 2, 1). Why?

Comment: Is it because your inputs value is `Input(shape=(1,6))` and emb value is `Input(shape=(2,1))`?

Comment: I could get the correct summary by manually overwriting def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (None, input_shape[1], 6) in my layer. I still wonder, though, do I always need to do that/ do I need to do something else to use this custom layer safely etc.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Keras, yet.  I'll keep checking, but you're probably correct.  Even on the documentation page, the first example has a new `build` method where `input_shape` is being indexed.  https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the compute_output_shape method in the layer:

```
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
    def call(self, emb):
        emb = K.repeat_elements(emb, 6, 2)
        return emb
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (None, input_shape[1], 6)
```